# Assigning a value to a struct indexer

Tags: c#, indexing, struct

I'm getting the compiler error 'Cannot modify the expression because it is not a variable'. I understand that one cannot assign a value to a struct property because a copy of a struct is returned, but I don't think that applies in this case.

I have a DualArray class whose purpose is to keep two arrays in sync. I want to access items in the 'first' array using the A property, and items in the 'second' array using the B property. These properties return structs that have an indexer into the respective arrays.

```
public struct Accessor<T>
{
  private readonly T[] _array;
  public Accessor(T[] array)
  { _array = array; }
  public T this[int index]
  {
    get { return _array[index]; }
    set { _array[index] = value; }
  } 
}
/// <summary>
/// Maintains two arrays.
/// </summary>
public class DualArray<T1, T2>
{
  // ...
  public Accessor<T1> A
  {
    get { return new Accessor<T1>(_arrayT1); }
  }
  public Accessor<T2> B
  {
    get { return new Accessor<T2>(_arrayT2); }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now when I try to use this code, I get the error:

```
DualArray<int, bool> dual = new DualArray<int, bool>();
// ...
dual.A[5] = 2; // <-- sad trombone.
```

If I change my accessor type to class it all works fine, but surely even if the struct is copied the reference to the relevant array is still valid? Or is the error in this case simply because I'm doing something I shouldn't, rather than an actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I understand that one cannot assign a value to a struct property
>   because a copy of a struct is returned, but I don't think that applies
>   in this case."

True, in this case it would not cause the bug that it normally causes.
But the compiler simply doesn't allow it because this writing-to-a-copy-of-a-struct has a great potential for causing bugs.

The error message contains the solution:

> Cannot modify a value type return value of `DualArray.A'. **Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.**

So, store it in a variable:

```
var a = dual.A;
a[5] = 2;
```

Comment: thanks, I figured it was probably a warning masquerading as an error just because it's such a serious one. Shame the solution sort of destroys the niceness of having a named accessor. I changed Accessor<T> to a reference type now, which allows me to keep the succinct assignment.

Comment: @DavidRutten: It's not "a warning masquerading as an error" - it's an error. The expression `dual.A` is classified as a value, not a variable. Therefore you can't use the indexer setter. Any compiler which *did* permit this would be violating the language specification.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I see, it's an error because it is defined as such, rather than because it is actually nonsensical. Fair enough, I understand why the spec designers felt it important to nip such dangerous code in the bud.

Comment: @DavidRutten: In almost all cases it *would* be nonsensical. It's only because your value type doesn't really behave as most value types are expected to (i.e. modification "via" a copy is still visible "via" the original).

Comment: "The expression `dual.A` is classified as a value, not a variable." *That* is what I should have said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
DualArray<int, bool> dual = new DualArray<int, bool>();
var acc = dual.A;
acc[5] = 2;
```

The original design error is due to the changing of the value-Type (returned from a method) properties directly which can cause unexpected results because that refers to a copy of the value-type. But in your case since you're mixing value-types inside reference types by storing the backing array from which you're constructing the struct inside a class, so you don't get that unexpected results.

From error [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c.aspx):

> This error occurs because value types are copied on assignment. When
>   you retrieve a value type from a property or indexer, you are getting
>   a copy of the object, not a reference to the object itself. The copy
>   that is returned is not stored by the property or indexer because they
>   are actually methods, not storage locations (variables). You must
>   store the copy into a variable that you declare before you can modify
>   it.
>
> If you are defining the class or struct, you can resolve this error by
>   modifying your property declaration to provide access to the members
>   of a struct. If you are writing client code, you can resolve the error
>   by creating your own instance of the struct, modifying its fields, and
>   then assigning the entire struct back to the property. As a third
>   alternative, you can change your struct to a class.

Comment: But there's nothing on my value type to change, it delegates everything back to the array it wraps, and arrays are reference types.

Comment: @DavidRutten `dual.A` returns a copy of the struct.

Comment: I did notice the alternative code worked, which is strange because, I still think, it does exactly the same thing. In fact I tested this, and the alternative works as expected.

Comment: @DavidRutten But it doesn't change the values inside `dual`. Try duplicating the code. `var acc = dual.A; acc[5] = 2; var acc2 = dual.A;` Then acc2 holds the original value and not the updated one to `2`

Comment: Yes it DOES change dual. Because the struct contains a REFERENCE to an array, and when that struct is copied, the new struct still contains a REFERENCE to that very same array. And as my indexer directly uses that array REFERENCE the code works as expected when specifically spread out across two lines.

Comment: @DavidRutten: No, it doesn't change `dual`. It modifies the array that the variable within side `dual` refers to, which is the same array that the copy of `dual` refers to. That's not changing `dual` itself at all.